# Is there a model that changes a path of a agent after colliding to an other object

Tags: agent, rinsim

the [CollisionPlaneRoadModel](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/rinde/rinsim/core/model/road/CollisionPlaneRoadModel.java) stops the movement of objects, are there models that try to find an other path when the path is occupied?

the CollisionPlaneRoadModel just say: `This model handles collisions between MovingRoadUsers by stopping the movements of colliding objects.`
Where can I find the functionality/function that is called when colliding?